# check username in databse and update[html,mysql,php]

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have been trying since yesterday, and almost covered all questions regarding this matter in Stackoverflow plus googling, but so far nothing is working with me, i try to check username availability before updating the username in database, however, it wont check and always update the username directly without error message regarding not availability of the name..

here my code

```
//new connection
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "student", "student", "C14D5");
if ($con->connect_errno) { //failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}
//success 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['clientN'])) {
        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT client_name FROM clients WHERE client_name='".$_POST['clientN']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {
            echo "<script>
alert('Username is not available, please select another username.');
</script>";
            header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  );
        } else {
            // run sql 
            $sql ="UPDATE `clients` SET `client_name` = '".$_POST['clientN']."' WHERE `client_ID` = '".$_POST['SelectClient']."'";
            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "<h3> New record created successfully</h3>";
                header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  );
            } else {
                echo "Error : " . $sql  . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }
            $con->close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aside from using unsecure SQL queries try to change if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) to if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Paul_M, it worked but now echo "<script>
alert('Username is not available, please select another username.');
</script>"; is not working

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, you have a logic flaw, you trying to update inexistent record, instead looks like you are inserting new record and need to check first if username already exists, if number of rows returned are equal 0 - add record, if not first check if username already in the table and update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `mysqli_num_rows()` function to avoid data duplication in your database

use this code :

```
//specify the database connection factors as usual ,then
$uname = $_POST['your_username_field'];    

$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_db where username='$uname'";
//the variable 'sql' will store the resultset of the query

$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
// the 'num_row' will store the number of rows which matches your $sql resultset. So if it is greater than '0' then the data already exists

if( $num_row > 0)
{
    // display 'username exists error'
}
else
{
   // Insert user name into your database table
}
```

If the num_rows is greater than 0 ,then the username is already present in your database table . So at that case throw error. else `INSERT` the user name into your database and display success message .